# How to enable mod_env in Apache

Tags: apache, xampp, apache2, mod-env

I'm trying to set Environment variables for PHPMailer and need to enable **mod_env** in the httpd.conf. I know if you're using Apache (and mod_env is enabled), then Envirnoment variables can be specified in .htaccess. Here is my httpd.conf in XAMPP:

```
Alias /bitnami/ "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs/"
Alias /bitnami "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs

<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mod_env is *loaded* or *enabled* like every other module, with the LoadModule directive. It's probably already enabled.  If it isn't, the pattern will be quite obvious.

You can check loaded modules with apachectl -M

If you want to use directives provided by mod_env, like "SetEnv" you'll have to actually look up their syntax in the manual and type them into your configuation.

Answer (score 3):

To enable mod_env: `sudo a2enmod env`

Then restart apache: `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

Answer (score 2):

I was running CentOS release 6.10 and did not have a2enmod available. 
I had to use yum: yum install ea-apache24-mod_env.x86_64
once installed, my 500 error went away and the SetEnv directive worked properly again.