# Internal Server Error after install 2.3.6 problem apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, magento2, http-status-code-505

I need help with the installation of Magento 2.3.6 this is returning an error in apache:

> core: alert] [pid 23385] [client 179.232.122.240:2423] .htaccess: Invalid comid command 'SetEnv', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

I already wasted a lot of time researching and tested a lot, but nothing worked, could someone help me?

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's administrative in nature, not related to programming as laid out in [help/on-topic]. On top, look at the pointers in the [tag:magento] tag, where this question _might_ be on topic. Also, Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447).

Answer (score 1):

> Invalid comid command 'SetEnv', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

This implies you don't have mod_env installed in Apache. You need to install/enable this module and restart Apache.

This is a little unusual since mod_env is considered a "Base" module and is "compiled and loaded into the server by default".

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html

---

To find out which Apache modules are enabled, check [@ValentinBajrami's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/475176/49157) to the following [question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/475173/how-to-list-apache-enabled-modules):

> To list apache loaded modules use:
>
> ```
> apachectl -M
> ```
>
> or:
>
> ```
> apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES
> ```
>
> or on RHEL,CentoS, Fedora:
>
> ```
> httpd -M
> ```

And the following question if you need to install/enabled mod_env:

- [How to enable mod_env in Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44740673/how-to-enable-mod-env-in-apache)

Comment: Thanks for answering

I have the impression the mod_env is already installed, it appears on the apache modules

how do I check if it is enabled?